What is the best way to add windows to this building?
I am making a building for my tiny city square but I have no clue how to add windows simultaneously. Will I have to do it all manually, or is there a way for me to make it more easy? (My topology is not good at all)


What do you mean, add windows? To me this looks like windows there or where else do you want to add windows?

As textures? As holes in the geometry? Procedurally or manually? It's unclear what you want, and what you're trying to do, and what you are asking for help with.

If you are wanting to apply a nice window material to many faces easily, the Select Similar tool will be helpful here.
Select one window pane, and then hit Shift + G.

Use the option "Coplanar", which will select all faces that are in the same plane as the one selected.

Then, it's simply a matter of hitting "Assign" in the materials tab, and all selected objects will now have the material!

Of course, if your window panes are somehow askew, this will not work, and you need to straighten them out with the axis they're supposed to be in plane with.


